# create even on slider change in extjs 4/5

Tags: extjs4, extjs5

create even on slider change in extjs 4/5, if i change slider then please occur an event in exths 5 please advice me

items: 
[{

```
            xtype: 'slider',
            fieldLabel: 'Probability',
            minValue: 400,
            maxValue: 2000,
            increment: 400,
            labelWidth: 150,
            width: 450,
            id: 'probSlider',
            name: 'probSlider',
            itemId: 'probSlider',
            listeners: {                    
                render: function (s) {
                    Ext.get(s.id).dom.addEventListener(
                        'change',
                        function (e) {
                            s.fireEvent('mousewheel', s, e);
                        },
                        false);

                }
            }
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slider is a form field so you don't install listeners to its underlying DOM but on the slider itself. See [change event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.slider.Single-event-change) docs.

Also, it seems to me, that you're trying to use slider to scroll an element, right? If so then don't try it by trying to fire hardware events artificially. There are methods to call for scrolling, for example [scroll method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-scroll).